# Changing 2 variables into 1 with passing output.close and input.close

Tags: ruby

I'm going through the Learn Ruby The Hard Way and I'm stuck cleaning the code up. When I run the ori code it doesn't yield any errors. When I run my code with the change, it runs everything but also add an error message. I'm not quite sure why. Please help.

```
ex17.rb:19:in `<main>': undefined method `close' for #<String:0x007febe4054c18> (NoMethodError)
```

ori.

```
from_file, to_file = ARGV
script = $0 

puts "Copying from #{from_file} to #{to_file}"

#we could do these two on one line too, how?
input = File.open(from_file)
indata = input.read()

puts "The input file is #{indata.length} bytes long"

puts "Does the output file exist? #{File.exist? to_file}"

output = File.open(to_file, "w")
output.write(indata)

puts "Alright, all done."

output.close()
input.close()
```

The changes I made was putting the input and indata together.

```
from_file, to_file = ARGV
script = $0 

puts "Copying from #{from_file} to #{to_file}"

#we could do these two on one line too, how?
input = File.open(from_file).read()

puts "The input file is #{input.length} bytes long"

puts "Does the output file exist? #{File.exist? to_file}"

output = File.open(to_file, "w")
output.write(input)

puts "Alright, all done."

output.close()
input.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in 1st code, in line `input = File.open(from_file)`, the type of `input` is `File`.

but in 2nd code, in line `input = File.open(from_file).read()` the type of `input` is `String`. and `String` has no `close` method.

Comment: In that case, if I take out the close method for the 2nd code. The output is the exact same for both codes, does that mean it is the same results?